# npm missing package error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When I build my js application, I get error that a package(say A@0.94.2) is missing.

I do:

> npm list A

This gives me a tree structure like this:

> ├── A@0.94.2
>
> └─┬ B@0.94.3
>
> ```
>   └── A@0.94.2  deduped
> ```

What does it mean?

Also, it seems A@0.94.2 is available, so why do I get error?

Edit: NPM verions is 5.6.0

Comment: Do both your application and B depend on A?

Comment: TBH, I have no idea. I am exploring this application,and trying to build it.

Comment: What is you `npm` version?

Comment: Take a look of your application's `package.json` and B's `package.json`, do you see `A` in the `dependencies` or `devDependencies` object?

Comment: Yes, application and B depends on A.

Comment: I think this is not an error, it literally says A is deleted from B since it already exists in the upper level (project). You could try to remove `node_modules` from the project directory, then run `npm install` and `npm list A` to see if it is still the same.